# Query to compare t month's and t-1 month's data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and having a hard time writing a select query to compare data from t month to t-1 month. Here is exactly what I want:

```
As_of_date      Customer        Status
1-Jan-11          1              A
1-Jan-11          2              A
1-Jan-11          3              A
1-Jan-11          4              A
1-Jan-11          5              A
1-Jan-11          6              A
1-Jan-11          7              A
1-Jan-11          8              A
1-Jan-11          9              A
1-Jan-11          10             A
1-Feb-11          1              A
1-Feb-11          2              A
1-Feb-11          3              A
1-Feb-11          4              B
1-Feb-11          5              A
1-Feb-11          6              A
1-Feb-11          7              B
1-Feb-11          8              A
1-Feb-11          9              A
1-Feb-11          10             A
1-Mar-11          1              A
1-Mar-11          2              B
1-Mar-11          3              A
1-Mar-11          4              B
1-Mar-11          5              B
1-Mar-11          6              A
1-Mar-11          7              B
1-Mar-11          8              A
1-Mar-11          9              B
1-Mar-11          10             A
```

I want to fetch for each month all those customers who have changed their status. So my result should give me:

```
As of Date      Customer    Status
1-Jan-11        4         A
1-Feb-11        4         B
1-Jan-11        7         A
1-Feb-11        7         B
1-Feb-11        2         A
1-Mar-11        2         B
1-Feb-11        5         A
1-Mar-11        5         B
1-Feb-11        9         A
1-Mar-11        9         B
```

See these are the customers who have changed their status from A to B as compared with previous month. Consider that there are only 2 statuses.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What version of sql server?  2012 should make this dead easy, just look up the lead and lag windowing functions.

Comment: Actually I am using Oracle sql developer

Answer (score 1):

This code is of SQL Server, Can use same logic.

```
With CTE as 
(
select As_of_date
,   Customer
,Status
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Customer,Status order by Customer asc,As_of_date asc,Status asc) rN
 from tblTest
)
select * from CTE as c
join CTE as c1 on c.Customer = c1.Customer
where c.rN = c1.rN
    and c.Customer = c1.Customer
    and c.Status <> c1.Status
```